# Whydoes FGA Oracle catch errors?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to make audit of table with special users. From `system` write:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_FGA.add_policy (
        object_schema   => 'system',
        object_name     => 'my_fga_table',
        policy_name     => 'my_fga_policy_1',
        statement_types => 'SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE',
        audit_condition => 'USER=''REFEREE_1'' OR USER=''REFEREE_2'''
   );
END;
```

From `REFEREE_1` I'm trying to change table:

```
UPDATE SYSTEM.my_fga_table SET points=90 WHERE boxer_name='BOXER_1';
```

Oracle answers:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
UPDATE SYSTEM.my_fga_table SET points=90 WHERE boxer_name='BOXER_1'
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 15
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-28138: Error in Policy Predicate
28138. 00000 -  "Error in Policy Predicate"
*Cause:    An invalid policy predicate was specified.
*Action:   Please specify a valide policy Predicate for the FGA policy
```

What's the poblem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Usage Notes section of the `DBMS_FGA` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_FGA.html#GUID-BE9BD27B-14AB-4742-B4C5-4A945349DC64), sixth bullet point:

> The `audit_condition` must be a boolean expression ...*[rest of paragraph snipped]*
>
> The expression must not combine conditions using operators such as AND and OR.

The problem is that you are combining two conditions using `OR`.

It seems you'll have to create two policies, one with `audit_condition` set to `'USER=''REFEREE_1'''` and the other with the condition set to `'USER=''REFEREE_2'''`.

Finally, please don't create objects in the `SYSTEM` schema, or other built-in Oracle schemas.  Oracle can refuse to support you if you've been doing this.

Comment: nice to know about `dbms_fga` but do you know how it differs from `dbms_rls` package ? I don't get enough while searching for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30: if you have a separate question to ask, please ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes that's a good idea but I have figured it out already.